# Can you only make an 'Investment' in one merchant total?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Ok, so with the Investor perk (Speech 70) you can make an investment in different merchants.  I've found a lot of them in the game giving up the offer and I've invested in about 5 different merchants so far, however, only the first one that I invested in has ever actually had an increase in money.

Can you only invest in ONE merchant?  Has anybody else invested in multiple merchants?
I know I can get the next perk up the chain to give everybody more gold overall but that isn't the issue.

Just not sure if this is a bug or a 'feature' for the PS3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every merchant I invested in has a persistent 500g increase (with the exception of the Riverwood Trader who has over 10000g but that's a different bug).  Try waiting 48 hours.  If they truly do not have more gold than before, it is a bug.

Comment: The riverwind trader was the first merchant i invested in and I expected him to have around 10k~ gold on him.  I'm about 90hrs (real time) into the game so I guess it is yet another bug :/

Comment: i'm about 500 hrs in RT Robots correct,and i usually wait 24 hrs then 24 minus however many hours to bring me to 9am. I also have the more money perk. if you find your problem persists i would suggest SAVING,then taking the perk and checking with your mechants again to see if this triggered a change :)